# How to change background image for focused state of edittext

Tags: android, colors, themes, android-edittext, border

I know the title of my question sounds like a question that already has been answered.
However, my question is somehow different and I couldn't find a solution

In my app I have a login screen with two EditText. I use a modified version of the Theme.Holo.Light.

The EditTexts look like this:

[image: EditText of Theme.Holo.Light]

As you can see there is a border below the text in different color, depending on the state of the EditText.

So here is my question: Can anyone tell me how to change the color of these borders??

I hope anyone can help me! Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Unfortunately, I ran into an other problem:

I was able to change the background image using solution of dtmilano.
However, adding a StateListDrawable removed the padding of the EditView. If I add text, the cursor is at the most left position, not inside the depicted border as before.
Up to now, I wasn't able to introduce this padding, e.g. with android:paddingLeft.

Can anyone tell me which property got overwritten by using this selector

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        >
        <item 
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_pressed" 
            /> <!-- pressed -->    
        <item 
            android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused"
            /> <!-- focused -->    
        <item 
            android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_default" 
            /> <!-- default -->
    </selector>
```

and an EditText like this:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_modified_states"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) as the background of your EditText in your theme so you can handle the different states.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ran into an other problem and edited my question. Can you help me, dtmilano?

Comment: Use [9 patches](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) so you can specify where to content goes